# When home button pressed, relaunch the application then open from starting

Tags: android, launch

In my application I have OTP enter screen, So i need to enter the otp in my last screen.For this I have 6 Screens, in this last screen is otp enter screen(ForgotPasswordEnterOTP). Here my problem is after 6th screen when home button pressed again open my application it will display the last screen(ForgotPasswordEnterOTP). **But while search my application from all the applications in device launcher screen then open my application then application will open from starting.** But here I need to display the last screen(ForgotPasswordEnterOTP). But if open the application without search then it is working fine. But getting issue while search the application only. I have tried with launch modes too. But no use.

this is the manifest file code

```
  <application
        android:name=".api.APIClient"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/title_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordOTP"
            android:label="@string/forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordEnterOTP"
            android:label="@string/forgot_password"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

/>
```

In this case only getting issue. while search my application then open it. In that time only getting issue.

[image]

So how to resolve this issue. Please guide me, Thanks for help.

Comment: did you try with different launcher?

Comment: No this is default launcher, Samsung device